# AWS RDS - Is the regional manual snapshot limit per cluster or shared among clusters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

The RDS limits documentation says there's a snapshot limit of 100 manual snapshots per region. I'm planning to use AWS backup to manage RDS snapshots, but it's unclear whether backing multiple clusters will add to the same limit of 100 snapshots.

Is there a separate limit for every single cluster within a region or do they share a common limit within the region:

RDS A: eu-west-1: 100 manual snapshots
RDS B: eu-west-1: 100 manual snapshots

OR

RDS A: eu-west-1: 50 manual snapshots
RDS B: eu-west-1: 50 manual snapshots

This would obviously make a huge difference in case there will be for example 10 clusters => limit 10 per cluster avg.

Answer (score 0):

The limit appears to be 200 on one of our accounts, although documentation I read specified 100, as you say.  This is manual snapshots per account per region.

Still not sufficient for 30 minute snapshots with 30 day retention :(

It does not appear to be linked to the cluster or DB directly and is across all DBs in each region.